# Evernote web note editor

Tags: web, editor, wysiwyg, evernote

I am developing a web app integrated with Evernote and was wondering if there is a way to use the **Evernote note editor** inside my app. 
Do they provide something through their API or maybe an URL to call with some specific arguments? I wasn't able to find anything.

If there is no way to use the Evernote editor I will probably end up using a custom WYSIWYG.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't provide a way to embed our note editor, but you can open a specific existing note for view or edit using the URLs https://host.evernote.com/view/guid and https://host.evernote.com/edit/guid, where host is the hostname (sandbox, www) and guid is the note GUID.