# Using the Evernote API to generate open links for the new Evernote web editor

Tags: hyperlink, editor, evernote

I'm trying to use the Evernote API to generate links to editable notes in the new Evernote web editor.

[image: new web editor image]

I've tried building the links as suggested by the [documentation](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/note_links.php) and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11760758/evernote-web-note-editor), but the resulting links take me to the old version of the Evernote web editor.

Appending **&ses=4&sh=2&sds=5&** to the end of links formatted like this:

```
https://www.evernote.com/Home.action#n=UID&ses=4&sh=2&sds=5&
```

fixes this problem, redirecting me to the desired note in the new web editor, but this doesn't seem like a very stable/reliable solution (it's probably safe to assume that these links will change).

Is there a different way I should be building these links in order to redirect to the new web editor?

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, so using the window location hash parameters to direct users to specific notes in the web client will work for the foreseeable future, but you're right, it's an unsupported API and you shouldn't depend on it. I'd recommend using [note links](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/note_links.php) to link to notes instead.